# Ansible equivalent of "passwd -l"

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm trying to lock a user account that I just created with Ansible (it should not be possible to log into this account). I know you can do this using the shell module by running "passwd -l".

Is there a way to do this via the user module, or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's not possible.

Maybe the following is an option?

```
 - user: 
     name: someone
     shell: /sbin/nologin
```

I think this is even more secure than using `passwd -l` as the latter would only disable the password. The user would still be able to login by ssh key authentication.

Comment: Except, in the case where you'd want someone to be able to access (ssh,rsync) via keys, but not be able to do interactive login, then using `/sbin/nologin` would also block rsync - that's when `passwd -l` is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute 'password_lock'
password_lock: yes

^^ This is the equivalent of 'usermod -L'

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for your answer, in the future be sure not to post answers in a "instant messenger" style "^^" and provide code in ` so that they are properly formatted e.g. `user: name='someone' password_lock='yes'`